# Is it possible to create splash screen to display PNG images without using *.DLL library?

Tags: installation, dll, inno-setup, splash-screen, edit

Is it possible to create splash screen to display PNG images without using *.DLL library?

If yes, then please help me create a specific code that can customize its display position on the screen, for example in the center of the screen or in whatever pain you like!
Also, is it possible to customize the splash screen display time?

I really want to create one myself, but due to my limited knowledge, I would like to ask for your help to learn more!